# Error in actionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, ioexception

I'm trying to create a button for importing CSV file and I'm getting this error:

```
actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in  cannot implement 
    actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in 
    java.awt.event.ActionListener; overridden method does not throw 
    java.io.IOException

public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {  
1 error
```

### Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(130, 130, 130)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(197, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(130, 130, 130)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(147, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    pack();
}

 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {                                         
     String xfileLocation;

    xfileLocation="C:\\tra\\data1.txt";

    BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xfileLocation));
    try{
    String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); // Read the first line of data.
    // The while checks to see if the data is null. If it is, we've hit
    //  the end of the file. If not, process the data.
    while (dataRow != null){
        String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
        for (String item:dataArray) { System.out.print(item + "\t"); }
        System.out.println(); // Print the data line.
        dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
    }

    // Close the file once all data has been read.
    CSVFile.close();

    // End the printout with a blank line.
    System.out.println();


     }
    catch(IOException e){
     }

}  

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}     

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes - look at the [declaration of the method you're implementing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29):

```
void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

It isn't declared to throw any checked exceptions. So you can't *add* a checked exception such as `IOException` with a `throws` clause. You'll have to either handle the exception in your listener, or convert it to an unchecked exception and throw that.

(Your exception handling is already far from ideal - within the method, you catch `IOException` and swallow it completely silently... failing to close the file in that case. You should close the reader in a finally block or using a try-with-resources statement if you're using Java 7, and you should *at least* log the exception, potentially telling the user about it. Continuing as if nothing had gone wrong is a really bad idea.)

Comment: ...and since your jButton1ActionPerformed does catch the IOException, you can remove the throws clause in jButton1ActionPerformed and therefor in the actionPerformed method as well

Comment: @Flo: Not quite - there's a `new FileReader(xfileLocation)` call *before* the `try` block. I wondered about that too :)

Comment: @user3209604: Which bit do you not understand? Do you understand how exceptions work in general, and checked exceptions? We can't write the code for you because we don't know how you want to handle errors. (As an aside, reading a file in a UI thread isn't ideal, but we'll leave that for the moment.)

Comment: I get that. Thank you very much.